How to find the average of two columns from different tables with a one to many relationship
I want to get the average time from one a patient came to when they had their first vital signs checked. It means that I have to check the time the visit was initiated (created_at) against the created_at of the first vital signs check (i.e. the oldest vital signs). This is to check patient waiting time vis-à-vis staff performance.
But my code pulls all the vital signs checked for all the patients and averages it with all the visits for all the patients which isn't what I want.
$averageFVRTime = DB::table('visits')
    ->selectRaw('AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(vital_signs.created_at, visits.created_at))) AS averageFVRTime')
    ->leftJoin('vital_signs', 'visits.id', 'vital_signs.visit_id')
    ->oldest('vital_signs.created_at')
    ->whereBetween('visits.created_at', [$shiftPerformance->shift_start, $shiftPerformance->shift_end])
    ->get()
    ->first()?->averageFVRTime;

I tried
performance.
But my code pulls all the vital signs checked for all the patients and averages it with all the visits for all the patients which isn't what I want.
$averageFVRTime = DB::table('visits')
    ->selectRaw('AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MIN(vital_signs.created_at), visits.created_at))) AS averageFVRTime')
    ->leftJoin('vital_signs', 'visits.id', 'vital_signs.visit_id')
    ->oldest('vital_signs.created_at')
    ->whereBetween('visits.created_at', [$shiftPerformance->shift_start, $shiftPerformance->shift_end])
    ->get()
    ->first()?->averageFVRTime;

I tried finding the min if the vital_signs.created_at column but it returns an 1111 invalid use of group function error.
I tried
$averageFVRTime = DB::table('visits')
    ->selectRaw('AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(vital_signs.created_at, visits.created_at))) AS averageFVRTime')
    ->leftJoin('vital_signs', 'visits.id', 'vital_signs.visit_id')
    ->oldest('vital_signs.created_at')
    ->whereBetween('visits.created_at', [$shiftPerformance->shift_start, $shiftPerformance->shift_end])
    ->havingRaw(MIN(vitl_signs.created_at)
    ->get()
    ->first()?->averageFVRTime;

using the havingRaw() method but it returns nothing, an empty collection.
Any ideas how I can do this with Laravel query builder?

If you want the average per patient, you need to use groupBy on the probably called patient id or something like that.

You might have some luck if you use relationships and use has one of many and get the average of the relationship you create. Documented in https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

@Raphi1 I want the average of the each visit's created_at and the first vital_signs created_at. So I need to create another table made up of each visit's first vital signs and call the average function on it. I just don't know how to do it with laravel's query builder

@apokryfos hmm... I will look into it. It means I will ditch query builder and use eloquent, right?

Yes it would mean that

This sounds like a "groupwise-max" problem (or min).

@Zuby can you please offer us a sufficiently large/challenging demo from phpize.online ?  If you load the table data, that sandbox will allow us to run Laravel queries.

@RickJames I don't think I have come across "groupwise-max". I will read it up. Thanks a lot.

@mickmackusa I will really like to do this. I think I will try and learn it so I can provide data in a sandbox. I had to do some hackish things. I added a column on the visit table that saves the datetime of the first vital signs saved. But I would love to make a relationship query of that sort work
